# How to insert blank rows when number of record is less than rows fixed in detail section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to fix Number of rows in detail section and insert blank rows if number of record less than rows fixed in detail section eg. Suppose there are fix 8 rows and if 2 rows are shown then 6 rows should be left blank?

Comment: do you mean white space for next 6 rows?

Comment: yes, but now the problem is solved :)

Comment: @Great.. Can you post as answer..

Answer (score 1):

First of all fix height detail section by right click on detail section
Detail Section->Section Expert click on paging Tab->Check in New Page Before checkbox and beside it (x+2)button write formula->
**(Suppose you want 8 rows to display in your report per page and additional rows(9th row,10th row and so on... to another page)**
IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 9) = 0 THEN
    TRUE
ELSE
    FALSE
so now your height is fixed.. and for blank rows
suppose 2 records/rows are coming from data table/data source then from 8 fixed rows , 6 rows should be blank rows for that..
design your detail section with fields and keep report footer(section 4) blank with with some spaces(i want 8 rows fixed so keep size of 8 rows blank assuming in report footer) and put footer details in your section 5(page footer)..

if your header or footer  is not visible on another page then put all header parts details in page header and footer details in page footer

:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use remainder formula.